# How do I correctly inherit System.Web.Http.ApiController into F#?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, f#, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to create an F# project/library that I can use to capture files from the current request from a web api controller, which is in a c# project.  I tried to inherit the api controller to gain access to the Request property but I get an error stating **the type 'ApiController' is not an interface type**. Not sure if I am even on the right track. What am I missing?

```
type fileGrab = 
    inherit System.Web.Http.ApiController

    new()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to inherit, you need to inherit from a particular constructor, like so:

```
type fileGrab() = 
    inherit System.Web.Http.ApiController()
```

without that, you are trying to inherit an interface which requires you to write your own methods.

Comment: So I tried that, but ran into another problem.  Now I get the error **This 'inherit' declaration has arguments but is not a type with a primary constructor.  Consider adding arguments to your type definition.** ApiController is an abstract class so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: You need to add `()` after the type name, to indicate you are making a class with a parameter-less constructor.

Comment: Christopher, Thanks for that clarification. That fixed it.